# Is it necessary for an Euclidean domain to satisfies Triangle inequality

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-domain

I am wondering whether there always exist a Euclidean function f that satisfies $$f(a+b) \le f(a)+f(b).$$
In all the ED I know, it seems to be true.
For example, integers, Gaussian integers, all the Fields I know. Intuitively, I guess that it should be true, though I haven't try hard in proof; so I want to know whether there is any existed theory suggesting this to be true or there is any counter example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counterexample for $R=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$. This is a Euclidean ring with Eulcidean norm function
$$
f(x+y\sqrt{2})=x^2-2y^2. 
$$
For $a=1+\sqrt{2}$ and $b=1-\sqrt{2}$ we have $a+b=2$, so that $f(a+b)=f(2)=4$, but $f(a)=f(b)=1^1-2\cdot 1^2=-1$.
So we have
$$
f(a+b)=4>-2=f(a)+f(b).
$$

Comment: I don't think that this is a counter-example to the question as posed. Showing that a particular Euclidean function does not satisfy the property does not prove that no Euclidean function will satisfy it.

Comment: I was assuming norm-Euclidean. So "always" is not true, since we can chose $R$ as above, where there is no norm-Euclidean function $f$ with $f(a+b)\le f(a)+f(b)$.

Comment: "Is it necessary for an Euclidean domain to satisfies Triangle inequality?"  "Euclidean domain" is specified in the question, "norm-Euclidean" is not.  But we would need the original poster to clarify the question to decide between our two interpretations.